# Oracle Databases installation on macos

Tags: oracle

How can I install Oracle databases on macos natively without using a VM?!

tried every possible way, read almost all the documentations on their website but unfortunately i couldn't get any solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, not today. You can easily get up and running with a VirtualBox appliance, we even make one for [you to download and import.](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html)

VirtualBox recently put out an update that supports M1/M2 chip architectures, so that's nice.

Otherwise you could spin up an Always Free Oracle Autonomous Database Cloud Instance. That takes about 5 minutes, and then you could use that as your dev instance.